# Google Search not displaying results from sub-pages

Tags: search-engines, google-search

I published a new site with some delicate content on September 26, 2012 UTC and no results from sub-pages - only from the main page - appear in Google Search. Entering "neven lovrić" "cat out of the bag" into Google Search finds the main page. Is this type of behavior normal?

I ask this because the first site was ceased - my account was locked - by the NameCheap, Inc. Risk Assessment Team, allegedly due to PayPal, Inc. reversing my payment for the extension of the registration of the domain before I was able to publish any content on it.

In 2011 UTC, Google, Inc. blocked all results for certain keywords from being displayed to their users in the Arab Republic of Egypt during the demonstrations there. So, considering previous events, this is not an unlikely scenario in this case, also.

Answer (score 1):

It takes time for a small, new, previously suspended - simply not "healthy" to have its subpages indexed. You may have to wait a few more days to see it in search results.

I don't know how Google will handle your site, but I don't think it is censored. You are ranking behind this page in search results, but your site is young and do not have a single link. You need some link to make Google index your site faster

Comment: This site - catoutofthebag.info - was not previously suspended; catoutofthebag.orgs' registrar account is locked.

Comment: This domain*...

Answer (score 1):

Even if you had no problems with your account or domain it takes time for Google to crawl new sites completely.  Give it a little more time and you should see each one of your pages indexed one by one, unless you have done something on the page to get yourself de-indexed (black hat SEO techniques).

Comment: My Search Engine Optimization (SEO) technique is writing as much information as possible; there are no hacks except being very detailed in the text (e.g. writing both the full name and the abbreviation - however, this is also for readers unacquainted with the meaning of an abbreviation - or writing both the Croatian and the English name of something to get both terms indexed for the respective language searches - even though in ~50% of the cases this is also meant for the reader as the name translated into English alone might be meaningless to Croatian readers).

Comment: You can try submitting a sitemap to google of all your links, or even submit each page one by one to see if they get picked up faster.

Comment: Alright. However, note that the additional reason for my fear is that either NameCheap, Inc., Google, Inc., or third parties in the middle blocked almost all of my incoming e-mail at neven@lovric.net, forwarded by NameCheap, Inc. and hosted by Google, Inc., around May 20, 2012 UTC, after sending Cat out of the Bag 1 (no revision) to several recipients.

Comment: Well, it is certainly possible you tripped a spam alert and are being blacklisted as a spammer as a result (however that doesn't explain only your deep links not being picked up).  You might try contacting your hosting provider to see if your IP is blacklisted.  If you are using a shared hosting account, more than likely the whole IP is blacklisted somewhere (as spammers are on a LOT of shared IP addresses).  I gotta ask, tho, how old is this website of yours? Age of your site is a definite factor in how deep spiders crawl your links.

Comment: It is on a shared hosting account. The domain was registered and the hosting set up a month and a half ago; however, the sites' content was published on September 26, 2012 UTC.

Comment: http://www.catoutofthebag.info/sitemap.xml - no effect.

Comment: Your content was posted a week ago.  Seriously, you need to give it a while longer to see all of your pages indexed in Google (and some deep links just might not for a long while). Bing can sometimes take MONTHS to process all your pages (if they index them all).  What you need to focus on is building great, keyword rich content and invite people to link to that content.  Submit a sitemap to google, get your name out there, set up Facebook and Twitter, etc.  If you haven't gotten anything else indexed in 30 days, then start worrying about why.

Comment: Ok, someone finally gave me some kind of deadline for the indexing. Btw. I have already submitted the sitemap from my previous comment. I've examined the visitation logs and see that Googlebot has visited only the main page.